# Increase number of form inputs with js or php

Tags: javascript, php

I've created a script for a project using php and mysql to allow users to create questions with multiple choice answers. By default I've set it so that you can only have one question in your quiz but I am trying to add a button that when clicked you can add new input box's in order to add more questions to your quiz. I thought I should do this in javascript because it is client side and therefor wont alter what is already entered in the previous input boxes? I tried a for loop with a counter and increment the counter on click but this doesn't seem to work because I think the page needs to refresh. I don't mind if the solution is in php or javascript.

```
var limit = 1;
function addQuestion(){
limit++;    

}

for(var  i=1; i <= limit; i++){
document.write("Question "+i+":<input type='text' name='Question"+i+"'>"); 
}
```

Comment: I think your question is a little confusing.

Comment: I'm not particularity good at explaining these things sorry. Basically I have a for loop that displays input boxes a set number of times according to a limit. I want to increase the limit by pressing a button or link.

Comment: You need to show more of the code that adds the HTML.

Comment: what's in the for loop?

Comment: I've updated my question. It is just a documet.write with input box's. I know this bit works because if I declare the limit at say 5 then I get 5 boxes. Just I want to be able to change the limit using a button click then run the loop again so that a new box appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="inputFields">
   Question 1:<input type='text' name='Question1' /><br />
</div>
<button onclick="addQuestion();">New row</button>
```

If you use jQuery:

```
var limit = 1;
function addQuestion(){
   limit++;    
   $("#inputFields").append("Question "+limit+":<input type='text' name='Question"+limit+"' /><br />"); 
}
```

Or plain  JavaScript:

```
var limit = 1;
function addQuestion(){
    limit++;    
    var theList = document.getElementById("inputFields");
    var newEl = document.createElement("p");
    var newText = document.createTextNode("Question "+limit+":");
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type = "text";
    newInput.name = ("Question" + limit);
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
    newEl.appendChild(newInput);
    theList.appendChild(newEl);
}
```

Comment: This seems to have the effect of showing a blank page with just that one input box rather than adding it bellow the existing one. It's definitely the right idea though.

Comment: @user1627774 This can be fixed by NOT using `document.write` (you really shouldn't usually use this) I'll give an example.

Comment: Ahh okay, so what would I use as an alternative?

Comment: That works now, I just need to change it to add my drop down questions but I can manage that :) Thanks very much

Comment: All right, good :) be sure to use the latest edit as I made some minor changes

Comment: Sorry new problem with this. I've just tried it out and if I enter text in one field and then add a new field the text disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
        var limit = 1;
        function addQuestion()
        {
            limit++;
            $('input:last').after('Question ' +limit +'<input type="text" name="Question '+limit+'" />');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" /><br/>
</form>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add Question">

<script>
    var limit = 5;

    //this is to target the form element, you could use an ID as well for example;
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

    var button = document.getElementById("add");
    button.onclick = addQuestion;

    function addQuestion(){
        var currentInputs = form.elements.length;
        if(currentInputs < limit){
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            input.setAttribute('name', 'question'+(currentInputs+1));

            form.appendChild(input);
            form.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        } else {
            alert('maximum questions reached!');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the way to go about doing this is JavaScript (no need to involve PHP).

Basically, when your button gets clicked, you need to call a function which will append the necessary elements to the DOM. Your `for` loop NEEDS to be inside of this function.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){ addQuestion(3); }, false);

function addQuestion(limit)
{
    limit = limit || 1;

    var form = document.getElementById('my_form'), input;

    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        input = document.createElement('input')
        input.type = 'text';
        input.className = 'foo';

        form.appendChild(input);
    }
}
```

To explain, when your button gets clicked, JavaScript will call function `addQuestion`. All of your logic needs to be inside of that function (loops, appending/creating new elements etc.). If possible, use a library to help with this.

EDIT: I see the question has already been answered, however I am going to leave this answer as the other answers introduce unnecessary global variables and create elements from strings, which is not the best practice.